# Error in react-native with expo: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm building my first react native app and I encountered a problem to connect to redux store (I also do not have much experience with redux yet). I am using expo.

The error is:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
>
> This error is located at:
> in Connect(App) (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
> (...)

Here is my code:

Could you please help?

```
// App.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppStackNav from "./navigators/AppStackNav";
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import guestsReducer from "./reducers/GuestsReducer";

const store = createStore(guestsReducer);

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addGuest = (index) => {
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppStackNav
                    screenProps={{
                        currentGuests: this.state.currentGuests,
                        possibleGuests: this.state.possibleGuests,
                        addGuest: this.addGuest
                    }}
                />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        currentGuests: this.state.current,
        possibleGuests: this.state.possible,
        addGuest: this.addGuest
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

```
// GuestsReducer.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    current: 10,
    possible: [
        'Guest1',
        'Guest2',
        'Guest3',
        'Guest4',
    ],
};

const guestsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
    guests: guestsReducer,
});
```

```
// AppStackNav.js

import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Dashboard from "../screens/Dashboard";
import Project from "../screens/Project";
import Placeholder from "../screens/Placeholder";

const AppStackNav = createStackNavigator({
    // ...
});

export default createAppContainer(AppStackNav);
```

Comment: why are using this in your `mapStateToProps` function ? and why are you mapping your internal component function `addGuest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Issue**

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ guests }) => {
        return {
            currentGuests: guests.current,
            possibleGuests: guests.possible
        };
      }
```

**Second Issue**

You wire redux store to your upper level component which is the `App` component ... and then use `connect` and `mapStateToProps` to access `redux store` in the `children` of this upper level component (App) ...  I mean you connect your store via `mapStateToProps` to your `AppStackNav` component not the `App` component

```
const AppStackNav = ({ currentGuests, possibleGuests }) => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator({...});
    return <Stack />;
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ guests }) => {
    return {
        currentGuests: guests.current,
        possibleGuests: guests.possible
    };
  }

// react-navigation v2 is needed for this to work:
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppStackNav);
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addGuest = (index) => {
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppStackNav />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation! However, there's an issue in my AppStackNav now. When I do `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppStackNav)`
then I get an error:
> Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly.
I also tried:
```const Navigation = createAppContainer(AppStackNav);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navigation);```
but then I get "undefined is not an object" error.
Can you help me and explain how to use both connect and createAppContainer in this case?

Comment: @karo50560 you're welcome ... i updated the answer ... check it out

Comment: Hmm I'm still having issues, namely:
`const mapStateToProps = ({ guests }) => {
    return {
        currentGuests: guests.current,
        possibleGuests: guests.possible
    };
}
export default createAppContainer(connect(mapStateToProps)(AppStackNav));`
gives me error `undefined is not an object` pointing at `<AppStackNav />` in App.js. Do you know where the problem could be...?

Comment: @karo250560 you can git rid of this `createAppContainer` thing altogether by >> downgrading to `react-navigation` ***v 2** .. ((this is the version I'm currently using in all of my projects))

you can downgrade by running this command in your terminal: `>>npm install --save react-navigation@2.18.3` ... then you could delete `createAppContainer` ... if any errors fire, feel free to comment here, and I'll try my best to help...

Comment: It worked, you're my hero! xx Thanks for all the explanations and for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can't use 'this' keyword outside the class as It wont be able to understand the context for that particular method.

you need to simply remove `this` keyword from `mapStateToProps`

like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        currentGuests: state.current,
        possibleGuests: state.possible
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, that was indeed my mistake, but it did not solve fully my problem